# Given an array of integers. Find the Inversion Count in the array

Tags: java, arrays, mergesort

I tried to solve this problem but I,m getting the Wrong Answer
Inversion Count: For an array, inversion count indicates how far (or close) the array is from being sorted. If the array is already sorted then the inversion count is 0. If an array is sorted in the reverse order then the inversion count is the maximum.
Formally, two elements a[i] and a[j] form an inversion if a[i] > a[j] and i < j.

[enter link description here](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/inversion-of-array-1587115620/0/?category%5B%5D=Arrays&category%5B%5D=Arrays&company%5B%5D=Amazon&company%5B%5D=Amazon&problemType=functional&page=1&sortBy=submissions&query=category%5B%5DArrayscompany%5B%5DAmazonproblemTypefunctionalpage1sortBysubmissionscompany%5B%5DAmazoncategory%5B%5DArrays#)

```
class Solution
{
    // arr[]: Input Array
    // N : Size of the Array arr[]
    //Function to count inversions in the array.
    static long count = 0;
    static long inversionCount(long arr[], long n)
    {
        // Your Code Here
        long merged[] = mergeSort(arr, 0, n - 1);
        return count;
    }
    static long[] merge(long left[], long right[])
    {
        long res[] = new long[left.length + right.length];
        long i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
        while (i < left.length && j < right.length)
        {
            if (left[(int)i] <= right[(int)j])
            {
                res[(int)k] = left[(int)i];
                k++;
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                count = count + (left.length - i);
                res[(int)k] = right[(int)j];
                k++;
                j++;
            }
        }
        while (i < left.length)
        {
            res[(int)k] = left[(int)i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        while (j < right.length)
        {
            res[(int)k] = right[(int)j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
        while (i < left.length)
        {
            res[(int)k] = left[(int)i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        return res;
    }
    static long[] mergeSort(long a[], long lo, long hi)
    {
        if (hi == lo)
        {
            long temp[] = {a[(int)hi], };
            return temp;
        }
        long mid = (hi + lo) / 2;
        long left[] = mergeSort(a, lo, mid);
        long right[] = mergeSort(a, mid + 1, hi);
        long merged[] = merge(left, right);
        return merged;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? What happens when you run it, and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

As gfg uses many test cases to check your code , the answer that you get on the first test cases gets hold to the static variable(count) and will never be reset.

So only the first test case will be correct and the rest of the test cases gets the wrong answer.

So try declaring the count variable outside the method and initiate it within the method.Whenever a new test case is executed your count variable will be reset to zero.

```
    static long count;
    static long inversionCount(long arr[], long n)
    {
        // Your Code Here
        count = 0;
        long merged[] = mergeSort(arr, 0, n - 1);
        return count;
    }
```